# Why did Shimshon ask his parents to help him marry a Philistine woman?

Tags: tanach, shoftim--book-of, shimshon-samson

In  the 14th perek of [Sefer Shoftim](http://www.sefaria.org/Judges.14?lang=bi) the pasuk reads:

Translation is via [Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/?home)

וַיַּ֗עַל וַיַּגֵּד֙ לְאָבִ֣יו וּלְאִמּ֔וֹ וַיֹּ֗אמֶר אִשָּׁ֛ה רָאִ֥יתִי בְתִמְנָ֖תָה מִבְּנ֣וֹת פְּלִשְׁתִּ֑ים וְעַתָּ֕ה קְחוּ־אוֹתָ֥הּ לִּ֖י לְאִשָּֽׁה׃

"On his return, he told his father and mother, 'I noticed one of the Philistine women in Timnah; please get her for me as a wife'."

If Shimshon wished to marry a Philistine, why did he ask his parents to "Redt the Shidduch" (arrange the marraige) if he (presumably) knew that they would not approve?

I presume that marriages were usually arranged and that's why he asked them, or is there more to it with him asking such?

Comment: 1+ for Redt the Shidduch

Answer (score 1):

The rest of the story tells about his parents agreeing, coming down from the hills towards the coastal regions to arrange the marriage.

So, evidently, asking them was a good move on his part.

Comment: This still doesn't answer why he thought that it was the best course of action to go to his parents.